# LINQ to XML query does not read my XML file

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have created a project on Book Store and wanted to give Discounts. I have used XML file for that and tried to use LINQ query to retrieve data from that file every thing is okay but when I run the project it gives me an error NullReferenceException.
Here is the code of LINQ query.

```
string discountFilePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/App_Data/DiscountSettings.xml");
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(discountFilePath);
IEnumerable<XElement> filteredDiscounts;
filteredDiscounts = from d in xmlDoc.Descendants("Discount")
                    where Convert.ToDateTime(d.Element("StartDate").Value) < DateTime.Now 
                    && Convert.ToDateTime(d.Element("EndDate").Value) >= DateTime.Now
                    select d;
XElement discountElement = filteredDiscounts.LastOrDefault();
string discounCategory = discountElement.Element("GenreName").Value;
```

And here is my xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DiscountDetails>
  <Discount>
    <GenreName>Biographies</GenreName>
    <StartDate>2016-05-01</StartDate>
    <EndDate>2016-05-31</EndDate>
    <DiscountPercentage>10</DiscountPercentage>
  </Discount>
</DiscountDetails>
```

Please Help me with this

Comment: Could you include your NRE and where it is in your OP, please?

Comment: Also, try setting your `discountFilePath*...*`Server.MapPath()` to use tilde (`~`) for the path: `Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/DiscountSettings.xml"); this creates the path using the application's working directory - it might be trying to use an absolute path to "/App_Data/..."?

Comment: What line causes the error? Please, debug your programme to find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Important**

When You use `LastOrDefault()` method You must understood the method can return default value of object `(default(XElement))` and can by null and You will need to chceck if value is null. For example for Your code:

```
if (discountElement != null)
{
  string discounCategory = discountElement.Element("GenreName").Value;
}
```

Exept this Your code is good. Problem is the XML file and value of `StartDate` an `EndDate`. Change that value of tags as You have the where condition like `StartDat < DateTime.Now` and `EndDate >= DateTime.Now`, for example like this (for today)

```
    <StartDate>2016-05-01</StartDate>
    <EndDate>2017-05-31</EndDate>
```

When

`filteredDiscounts.LastOrDefault();` will not return null and all will by good.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't notice that dates. As I was creating it in May, I put the dates for May only. And yes It works now. @blogprogramisty.net

Comment: Sorry, it was me..since we answered completely together, but my answer was accepted first, then I wanted to put +1, since its correct..but then Roshini changed accepted answer from mine, so I wanted to undo it..looks like its not possible to make 0 from +1..and now I cannot undo the -1 either, says editation is required since its more then 20 min

Comment: @PetrAdam Ok, I eddited my answer and I give You upvote since Your answer is good too

Comment: thanks, im new to this voting, had no idea I cannot just remove upvote by clicking down, as I said, it changed to downvote instead:) (would expect to become 0, +1 -1 = 0)

Comment: @PetrAdam thx. Yes it is not celar for me too but It is like You said. More info http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251233/5816153

Comment: Your answer was half @PetAdam. I dint notice that when I accepted your answer. Sorry for that. and by the way me too new for this voting things.

Answer (score 1):

Check your dates in your XML. **filteredDiscounts** is empty, since your dates are wrong and nothing match your selection (today is `2016-06-21`)

Here you are trying to call LastOrDefault on `null`:

```
XElement discountElement = filteredDiscounts.LastOrDefault();
```